# android TextView no line break

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a TableView with some table rows. one of them is this (I have 2 of this structure in the table):

```
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trTimeSettingEndTime"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_recent_history" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="Start Time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTimeSettingEndTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
        </TableRow>
```

the image is at the right size. the middle textview takes out all the available space and the right textview width is it's content.

first thing I don't understand is why is the middle textview takes out all the space?

second, when I change tvTimeSettingEndTime textview from code and it's a bit longer then the text break a line instead of adjusting it's width.

can someone explain why is the middle on taking most of the space?

how can I make it that the third line would adjust it's width according to the text I put into it from code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the first column to be a static width (already working), the 3rd column to be the width of the contents (wrap_content), and the 2nd column to fill the available space. If so, try using a weight + 0dp width for the 2nd column, and wrap_content for the 3rd column.

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/trTimeSettingEndTime"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_recent_history" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="Start Time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeSettingEndTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />
    </TableRow>
```

If you want the 2nd and 3rd to be equal widths, set them both to weight=1 and width=0dp.

Also keep in mind a TableLayout will force columns to be the same width for each row, if you are looking for each row's columns to size independently, try using two horizontal LinearLayouts instead.